# Initialize subclass that requires `init(coder: NSCoder)`

Tags: swift, cocoa, nscoding

I want to subclass `CAShapeLayer` so it will hold a reference to the corresponding object in the data model:

```
class CPCoursePointLayer : CAShapeLayer
{
    let itsDataRef :CPCoursePoint
    let itsEventData :CPEventData

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init( coursePoint: CPCoursePoint, in eventData :CPEventData)
    {
        itsDataRef = coursePoint
        itsEventData = eventData
    }
}
```

Where `itsDataRef`and `itsEventData` are references (pointers if you like) to the underlying data. This way I can update the model if I have moved the an instance of may layer class, or draw it using graphic styles specified in the `eventData`.  My `CPCoursePointLayer`does not *own* these variables, to use a Rust term.

Now that I'm required to implement a `init(coder:)` initializer, how do I initialize my instance variables from nothing? Can I decode a 'pointer' from the `NSCoder`? That doesn't make sense to me...

Although I'm never going to call `init(coder:)`, myself, I guess it's there because the system might call it.  Then I will have an instance that is unusable...

I want to avoid the extra burden of doing the extra `if let` in every method if I declare my instance variables as optional (?).

Comment: You can implement the method and just have it throw a fatal error since you won't be using it.

Answer (score 2):

You essentially have three options:

1. Declare the variables as implicitly unwrapped optionals
2. Have `init?(coder:)` fail, either fatally or not
3. Have `CPCoursePoint` and `CPEventData` implement unarchiving via `init?(coder:)`

### Option 1:

```
class CPCoursePointLayer : CAShapeLayer
{
    let itsDataRef :CPCoursePoint!
    let itsEventData :CPEventData!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init( coursePoint: CPCoursePoint, in eventData :CPEventData)
    {
        itsDataRef = coursePoint
        itsEventData = eventData
    }
}
```

This will result in a crash if you reference `itsDataRef` or `itsEventData` and your object wasn't initialised by your new initialiser.

### Option 2(a)

```
class CPCoursePointLayer : CAShapeLayer
{
    let itsDataRef :CPCoursePoint
    let itsEventData :CPEventData

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }

    init( coursePoint: CPCoursePoint, in eventData :CPEventData)
    {
        itsDataRef = coursePoint
        itsEventData = eventData
    }
}
```

This will simply fail to initialise the object if `init(coder:)` is used.

### Option 2(b)

```
class CPCoursePointLayer : CAShapeLayer
{
    let itsDataRef :CPCoursePoint
    let itsEventData :CPEventData

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) is not supported for this class"
    }

    init( coursePoint: CPCoursePoint, in eventData :CPEventData)
    {
        itsDataRef = coursePoint
        itsEventData = eventData
    }
}
```

This will cause your program to crash if `init(coder:)` is called.

### Option 3

```
class CPCoursePointLayer : CAShapeLayer
{
    let itsDataRef :CPCoursePoint
    let itsEventData :CPEventData

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let itsDataRef = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:"itsDataRef"),
              let itsEventData = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:"itsEventData") else {
            return nil
        }
        self.itsDataRef = itsDataRef
        self.itsEventData = itsEventData
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init( coursePoint: CPCoursePoint, in eventData :CPEventData)
    {
        itsDataRef = coursePoint
        itsEventData = eventData
    }
}
```

Option 2(b) is probably the most common as it is a "fail fast" - You should catch this during testing pretty quickly if that initialiser is called.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution, if you don't want to support `NSCoding` in your subclass, is to `fatalError` in `init(coder:)`. In fact, the compiler will even offer that as a fix-it if you omit the initializer entirely:

[image: fix-it]

So just do that:

```
class CPCoursePointLayer: CAShapeLayer {
    let itsDataRef: CPCoursePoint
    let itsEventData: CPEventData

    init(coursePoint: CPCoursePoint, in eventData: CPEventData) {
        itsDataRef = coursePoint
        itsEventData = eventData
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

The system does not normally try to decode an instance of your custom layer.